# How to add target platform to oomph project setup file?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, oomph

I have a .target file for my project. Now wanted to set the target platform in oomph setup prior to project import. currently following [turorial site](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/oomph-basic-tutorial/)
but doing so getting only this annoying dialog and don't know how to fix this: 
[setup->new Child-> Additional Tasks->Target Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNal9.png)
and same for new targlet
although the expected one was as per the tutorial link. sorry can't add one more URL. still a green horn in stack overflow ;(

Answer (score 0):

Oomph is asking you to install an additional oomph task type. After installation and an eclipse restart you should be able to add the task to your setup